# Control order of JUnit test execution in InteliJ IDEA?

Tags: testing, junit, execution, intellij-14

How can I order the execution of my test methods at InteliJ IDEA in the same order that it appears in the testing class?
I only found the button to "sort alphabetically"

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Unit tests should be independent of one another; the need to order them suggests poor test design.

Comment: I know the principle of testing design and I don't have dependencies between test methods. It's only for visualization...

Comment: Sometimes you get handed tests that are broken if they run in a certain order.  It's important to be able to reproduce the problem in order to fix it.  Ideally no such tests would exist, but when you have them, you need the tools to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

This is not dependent of IDEA but JUnit.

Junit 4.11 comes with `@FixMethodOrder` annotation. You can annotate your class with `FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` and change the name of your methods so they will run in a sequence

Comment: The OP doesn't want alphabetical sorting.